# Does not boot ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I had Ubuntu installed. When I installed ubuntu I completely formated the hard disk and then I made 3 partitions, one for root, one for home, and one for data.I left 25 Gb unused.
All partitions were ext 4. After some months now I have installed the Windows 8 in the free space(24GB) . Now it directly boots Windows 8 and does not ask for the choice between Windows 8 and ubuntu . I can only access the partition in which I have installed the Windows. I want it to ask for choice between Windows 8 or ubuntu or some other way to run ubuntu or to access the data in the other partitions . Because I have very imported data there. I'm using Hp Pavilion dv6 i3 . 320gig hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think your win8 install put the win8 bootloader in sector 0 (the so-called
MBR = master boot record,) and destroyed your grub loader there.

There is a story on linuxbsdos.com  (google dual boot win7 linux)
that may help you fix the windows boot-loader to boot your ubuntu system
if you can get grub written in your ubuntu boot directory. (This
will be chain loading from windows to grub.)

One good thing is that since your hp dv6 is pre win8, you probably 
do not have an uefi bios that would cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: PS.  use a live cd or dvd to run knoppix or some such to get grub written in your otherwise inaccessible ubuntu boot directory.

Comment: PPS.  You might also be able to use the live cd to overwrite the MBR with the grub stage1 bootloader.  This will restore your ubuntu system but make your win8 system inaccessible. I wouldn't do any of this stuff until someone with more detailed knowlege can produce the line-by-line steps that need to be done.